# Where(Hash) followed by Scoped Where(Hash) in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Simply put :

```
class Project
  scope :with_status_1, where(:status => 'test1')
  scope :with_status_2, where('status = ?', 'test2')
end


Project.where(:status => 'test1').where(:status => 'test2')
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test1' AND "projects"."status" = 'test2'

Project.where(:status => 'test').with_status_1
  Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test1'

Project.where(:status => 'test').with_status_2
  Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test' AND "projects"."status" = 'test2'

Project.where('status = ?', 'test').with_status_1
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test' AND "projects"."status" = 'test1'

Project.with_status_1.where(:status => 'test')
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test1' AND "projects"."status" = 'test'

Project.with_status_1.where(:status => 'test').with_status_1
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."status" = 'test1'
```

Why would the case #2 and #6 clear up the preceding conditions?

Edit: Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

`where` clause sends its args to `build_where`

```
def build_where(opts, other = [])
  case opts
  when String, Array
    [@klass.send(:sanitize_sql, other.empty? ? opts : ([opts] + other))]
  when Hash
    attributes = @klass.send(:expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates, opts)
    PredicateBuilder.build_from_hash(table.engine, attributes, table)
  else
    [opts]
  end
end
```

So in the case of `Hash` it will rewrite keys, as it appends new hash options to existing hash. And if you're passing a `String` or an `Array` it will sum it.

Comment: Following your argument, why would the statement #5 worked? It's the exact opposite of #2.